# Questions about scope in PHP - from a Java Programmer's Perspective

Tags: php, session, scope, request

I'm still fairly new to PHP and so I'm attempting to understand scope concepts within PHP web applications.

In the Java world a Java web app - using Java Server Pages (JSP) and upward - will allow a Java Bean to have the following levels of scope:

- Page
- Request
- Session
- Application

Attempting to map these to PHP's scoping capabilities:

- Page: not really but objects that are local to a call are considered 'gone' after the function call is made so it's sort of like a page scope
- Request: made by using the "$_REQUEST super global (not sure where this goes ... Cookies? Hidden fields? URL parameters?)
- Session: using PHP's $_SESSION super global (where some of the documentation and forum feedback states that this is not a great place to put sensitive information for security reasons)
- Application: using PHP's APC (a Stack Overflow link)

Am I totally out to lunch or are these reasonably similar? I know that one major difference is PHP's ["Shared Nothing"][5] architecture as compared to Java's which is to allow for sharing.

Any advice/guidance/sobering corrections most welcome.

Comment: As for $_REQUEST, it contains all Cookie, Get, and Post data, which is why there's also $_POST, $_GET, and $_COOKIE superglobals for accessing each type individually.  $_POST is anything sent by POST, such as a form with method='post' (including hidden fields).   Their array key is the same as the name of their input.  $_GET is anything sent via the url, either by link or by form with method='get', i.e. `www.domain.com/index.php?page=1&whatever=yes` would have `$_GET['page']` which equals "1" and `$_GET['whatever']` which would equal "yes".  $_COOKIE is obviously everything stored in a cookie.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're on the right track.  PHP is indeed Share-Nothing.

In a web context, a php application runs, in it's entirety, once for each HTTP request.  This means for every HTTP request the interpreter reads, parses and executes the script (this is simplified - using an opcode cache like APC removes the reading/parsing overhead).

PHP feeds input to the script in the form of [superglobals](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php), such as $_REQUEST and $_SESSION.  Superglobals are different from regular global variables in that they're automatically available in every scope, so there's no need to use the `global` keyword.

Any data that persist between requests need to be stored externally.  To share data across requests to maintain state for a user, you typically use $_SESSION, which by default is serialized and written to files on disk (but can be configured to use a memory cache or database).  Data that are to be shared between sessions (which I suppose is similar to the Application scope in the JSP world) need to be stashed somewhere external.  You can use a memory cache like APC or memcache, or write flat files to disk, or stick stuff in a database, or use any other scheme you can come up with.  At the end of the day, there's nothing built-in.

Aside from superglobals, variable scope is fairly boring.  By default, variables live in the scope in which they're created.

To reference a global variable in a non-global scope (ie: inside a function), you need to import the symbol into the local scope using the `global` keyword.  PHP works this way to make it harder to accidentally clobber global variables.

This stuff, and more, is covered pretty [well in the manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php).

Comment: timdev, thanks for the response. I think I understand the concepts better.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably look at this:

http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

You've got local and global scope, superglobals, static variables. And that page explains how those each work.