# Add variables to symbol table from php function

Tags: php, cakephp

I am currently using CakePHP which makes heavy use of associative arrays. For one of the functions in my application it would be useful if I could create seperate variables from some of the data in these arrays. For example an array may look like this:

```
Array
(
    [User] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => Joe Bloggs
            [email] => test@test.com
        )

    [Post] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [title] => Hello World
        )

    [Profile] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [location] => London
       )

)
```

I would like to create a function that could split the array in 3 and give me three new variables.

I have had a look at [extract()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php) but it doesn't quite work in the way I would like. I would like to create three new variables as such:

```
$user: 

Array
(
    [User] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => Joe Bloggs
            [email] => test@test.com
        )
)

$post:

Array(
    [Post] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [title] => Hello World
        )
)

$profile:

Array(
    [Profile] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [location] => London
       )
)
```

Is it possible to create a function that would be able to add these variables to the symbol table or am I stuck only being able to return them?

Comment: You want something like `$post = array($user['Post']);`?

Comment: that seems a little redundant; why?

Answer (score 2):

```
$array = array(
 'value1'=> array('name' => 'john'),
 'value2'=> array('name' => 'sim')
);
function createVars($data) {
  foreach ($data as $key => $val) {
    global ${$key};
    ${$key} = $val;
  }
}
createVars($array);
// Now you should be able to access $value1 and $value2
```

Check out this link http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

Comment: what will be the scope of that variable? will it be accessible every where, or just within the function that it was called from?

Comment: You should also checkout the extract function http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php

Comment: This isn't quite working for me. I have created the function and registered the global variable but it is not available outside of the function. I have put the function in my AppModel class so that it is available to all my model's. Is it because they are separate classes that it is not available? If this doesn't make sense let me know and I will try and explain a little clearer.

I did look at extract() however it doesn't quite work in the way that I want it to work.

Comment: I'm afraid you will have to use the 'global' keyword in every function where you want to use these extracted variables. I think another approach might be to add the variables to the $GLOBALS array and then access them from that array in your functions. Have a look at this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4708508/questions-about-scope-in-php-from-a-java-programmers-perspective

Answer (score 1):

How does this work for you?

```
foreach( $input_array as $key => $value ){

   $variable_name = strtolower( $key );
   $$variable_name = array( $value );

}
```

Hope that helps...

Comment: I assume what I am looking for is the the $$? Does this make that variable available to the calling fuction? Where can I find information on this in the php manual, not sure what to search for as searching for '$$' doesn't get me much.

Comment: it uses the value of $variable_name as the variable name, which must be a string